# Deleted Queue by accident in SQS - can I retrieve it?

Tags: amazon-sqs

I deleted a queue by accident in Amazon SQS. Is there a way to retrieve/undo the delete?

Answer (score 5):

No, the queue (and any messages on the queue) are gone forever.

If you recreate the queue with the same name, it will keep the same ARN and URL. Hopefully you've got the configuration documented :-)